# Resolution of differential equations by polar coordinates

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a doubt respect to resolution of differential equations, for example if we have the family  of circles $x^2+y^2=2cx$, deriving $$2x+2y\frac{dy}{dx}=2c$$, combining $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y^2-x^2}{2xy}$$ and replacing $\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{dx}{dy}$, then we have the differential equation $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2xy}{x^2-y^2}(*)$$ We cannot find the solution of the last differential equation by separation of variables, but if we use polar coordinates in $x^2+y^2=2cx$ we get $$(r\cos\theta)^2+(r\sin\theta)^2=2c(r\cos\theta)$$ and $r=2c\cos\theta$, then $$\frac{dr}{d\theta}=-2c\sin\theta$$ and then $$\frac{r d\theta}{dr}=-\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}$$

The solution of the last differential equation is $r=2c\sin\theta$, so the solution of the differential equation (*) is $x^2+y^2=2cy$. 
Then my question is: why the change of coordinates permit find the solution of the differential equation? This is an accident or exit a theorem about this? And if exits such theorem, what kind of differential equation can be solve by change of coordinates? Thanks.

Comment: Somehow, you have gone from $x^2+y^2=2cx$ to $x^2+y^2=2cy$.

Comment: I'll add more information.

Comment: You have added more information, but you have not resolved the contradiction. In the second line, you have $x^2+y^2=2cx$. Later, you have $x^2+y^2=2cy$. These are *different*. One of them has an $x$ where the other has a $y$. How can both of them be the solution, when they are manifestly not equal to each other?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I think the problem is the step in which $$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=-\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}y}$$

Comment: @robjohn, yes, that step looks highly problematical, especially since what has actually been done looks more like $dy/dx=-1/(dy/dx)$.

Comment: That step is for to find the orthogonal family.

Comment: @JoséRamírez: Ah! that explains why you changed the slope to the negative of it's reciprocal. Having that stated in the question would have avoided my confusion, and perhaps Gerry Myerson's.

Comment: The orthogonal family? What orthogonal family? The phrase "orthogonal family" appears nowhere in your post. Mathematics is difficult, but mathematics plus mind-reading is nearly impossible. May I recommend that you edit your question so it says what you actually mean for it to say, and not something completely different?

Comment: The post is not about orthogonal family is about a solution of a differential equation by change of coordinates, that equation is visible is (*) and the solution too.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I interpreted "orthogonal families" to be what Wikipedia calls [Orthogonal Trajectories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_trajectory). I did notice that $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$ and $-\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}y}$ are the slopes of perpendicular lines, but since the problem did not mention anything about orthogonality, it seemed odd that we would simply exchange one for the other.

Comment: If the post is about ($*$), then may I suggest that you delete everything that comes before ($*$), or at least edit in something to the effect that everything that precedes ($*$) is completely irrelevant to the question you actually want to ask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solving (*)**

We can solve $(\ast)$ without changing to polar coordinates
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{2xy}{x^2-y^2}\tag{1}
$$
which can be manipulated to
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}y}\frac{x^2}{y}=\frac{2x}{y}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}y}-\frac{x^2}{y^2}=-1\tag{2}
$$
Integrating $(2)$ yields
$$
\frac{x^2}{y}=2c-y\tag{3}
$$
For some $c$. Therefore,
$$
x^2+y^2=2cy\tag{4}
$$

**Answer to the Question**

A change of coordinate may make the solution more apparent, but the equation should be solvable in either coordinate system.

Comment: The equation $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2xy}{x^2-y^2}(*)$$ is ok, but you don't answer the main question.

Comment: The main question was: "why [does] the change of coordinates permit [us to] find the solution of the differential equation?" My answer was "A change of coordinate may make the solution more apparent, but the equation should be solvable in either coordinate system."

Comment: The original equation $x^2+y^2=2cx$ has nothing to do with $(\ast)$ as written. That is the point which was confusing to me, and possibly to Gerry Myerson.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a substitution for the Bernoulli DE you obtain when considering $\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{x^2 - y^2}{2xy}$

Edit: Notice $\frac{dx}{dy}  = \frac{x^2 - y^2}{2xy} \Rightarrow x' - \frac{x}{2y} + \frac{y}{2x} = 0$, where $x'$ is obviously with respect to $y$

Comment: Could you be more expecific? That is not the exact form like here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_differential_equation

Comment: It appears to be for $n=-1$ where
$$
P(y)=\frac1{2y}\qquad\text{and}\qquad Q(y)=\frac x2
$$

Comment: But i know the answer of this, the problem is about this equation $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2xy}{x^2-y^2}(*)$$ and change of coordinates, you don't answer the main question.

Answer (score 0):

When you replace $\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{dx}{dy}$, you get

$$ \frac{dx}{dy}=-\frac{y^2-x^2}{2xy}= -\frac{y}{2x}+\frac{x}{2y} \rightarrow (1)\,. $$

It is easier to solve the differential equation (1). Let

$$u=\frac{x}{y} \implies x=yu \implies \frac{dx}{dy}=u+y\frac{du}{dy} \,. $$

Substituting back in $(1)$ gives,

$$ u+y\frac{du}{dy}= -\frac{1}{2u}+\frac{u}{2}\implies y\frac{du}{dy} =\frac{3u^2-1}{2u}\,. $$

Now, I think you can solve the last ode by the method of separation of variables to find $u$ as a function in $y$, then, substitute back $ u=\frac{x}{y} $.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this only now ... appears not to have been answered to your satisfaction.

You are not at all *changing coordinates*!! You are finding *orthogonal trajectories* of

$$ x^2 + y^2 + 2 c_1 x =0 $$ as

$$ x^2 + y^2 + 2 c_2 y =0. $$

with transformation $ y^{'} $  to $ -1/y^{'} $ *on the same coordinate axes*, which is the standard procedure to find orthogonal trajectories by a changed differential equation on same coordinate axes of same graph sheet (Red changes to Blue).

$ c_1, c_2 $ are parameters in each set of circles, displacement on axis = radius of circle. I shall not repeat the integration steps.

Their polar equations are

$$ r = 2 c_1  \cos\theta,\;\; r = 2 c_1  \sin \theta $$

The fist one is a set of circles centered on x-axis touching y-axis and passing through origin  and the second is the orthogonal set of circles centered on y-axis, also passing through the origin and touching x-axis as shown in the sketch

[image: TouchingCircles@Origin]

Incidentally, it is a special case of bipolar system of coordinates and also geodesics of the hyperbolic plane.